# Linking a c function and a asm assembly file

Tags: c, assembly, linker, nasm

I have a postfix program that does a while loop and prints 10 numbers, and it needs an extern print function which i defined, but for some reason after i create the object file if i do `ld -m elf_i386 -s -o p11 p11.o print.o` it gives me some strange errors.

what i want to do is link those files and create an executable that prints values from 1 to 10, but for some reason its giving me those errors when clearly what i want is use that c function to print those values

ps: if i use `gcc -m32 -o p11 p11.o print.o` i get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: p11.o: warning: relocation in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib32/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

commands:

```
$ nasm -f elf32 p11.asm -o p11.o
$ gcc -m32 -o print.o -c print.c
$ ld -m elf_i386 -s -o p11 p11.o print.o
```

Error:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008049000
ld: print.o: in function `print':
print.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `printf'
```

I dont get why because printf is defined in c and clearly coded somewhere

postfix program:

```
EXTERN print ; extern print(int)
DATA
ALIGN
GLOBAL ix, OBJ; static ix
LABEL ix
SINT 0; static ix=0
TEXT
ALIGN
INT 0
DUP32
ADDR ix
STINT
TRASH 4
ALIGN
LABEL whilecond
ADDR ix
LDINT
INT 10
LT
JZ endwhile
ADDR ix
LDINT
INT 1
ADD
DUP32
ADDR ix
STINT
TRASH 4
ADDR ix
LDINT
CALL print
TRASH 4
JMP whilecond
ALIGN
LABEL endwhile
```

assembly program:

```
extern  print
segment .data
align   4
global  ix:object
ix:
    dd  0
segment .text
align   4
    push    dword 0
    push    dword [esp]
    push    dword $ix
    pop ecx
    pop eax
    mov [ecx], eax
    add esp, 4
align   4
whilecond:
    push    dword $ix
    pop eax
    push    dword [eax]
    push    dword 10
    pop eax
    xor ecx, ecx
    cmp [esp], eax
    setl    cl
    mov [esp], ecx
    pop eax
    cmp eax, byte 0
    je  near endwhile
    push    dword $ix
    pop eax
    push    dword [eax]
    push    dword 1
    pop eax
    add dword [esp], eax
    push    dword [esp]
    push    dword $ix
    pop ecx
    pop eax
    mov [ecx], eax
    add esp, 4
    push    dword $ix
    pop eax
    push    dword [eax]
    call    print
    add esp, 4
    jmp dword whilecond
align   4
endwhile:
```

c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int num)
{
    printf("%d\n",num);
}
```

Comment: Add `-no-pie` to gcc command. Also you will obviously need a `main` function.

Answer (score 2):

> I dont get why because printf is defined in c and clearly coded somewhere

Because you are not linking that somewhere (namely, you are not linking with `libc`).

On UNIX systems, you should *never* use `ld` to link anything (with the exceptions of the kernel and boot loader).

Instead you should *always* use appropriate compiler driver (`gcc` here). Gcc will automatically add `-lc` to the link line.

P.S. you should also define the `main` program -- it's unclear how you expect your code to be invoked, since you defined nighter `main`, nor `_start` symbol.

> if i use `gcc -m32 -o p11 p11.o print.o` i get the following error:

Your `gcc` is configured to build PIE binaries by default, but your assembly is not written to be compatible with PIE.

Add the `-fno-pie` to your compile lines and  `-no-pie` flag to your link line.

Comment: `ld` can be used to link a hand-written static executable that *doesn't* use any libraries, just defines its own `_start` and uses system calls directly.  But yes, if you use any C libraries or want to link CRT code, you should let the C compiler's front-end do it, perhaps with `gcc -no-pie -fno-pie` if you wrote a `main`.  (Writing your own `_start` but using libc functions depends on dynamic linker support, and/or manually calling libc init functions from your _start.)

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: @Peter Cordes it worked in compiling but i still get the error `(.text+0x22): undefined reference to main` how can i do a main that starts my asm code and includes the print function?

Comment: @Martimc: You can't link that program without libc; your C code calls printf, therefore you need to link your program against a library that defines that symbol.  The compiler-generated asm will include a `call printf` or `call printf@plt`, so its object file symbol table will include a reference to that symbol, just like you you have `.extern print` in the file that does `call print`.  And you couldn't link that file into an executable without a .o that defines `print`.

Comment: @Martimc: If you wanted to make a stand-alone static executable with no libraries, you'd have to do something like [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894)